# Powerbuilder: Making certain rows editable and certain rows non-editable in a datawindow

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

how can I make certain rows editable and certain rows non-editable of a datawindow?

I am adding the rows using `pfc_addrow()` event of the datawindow, and I want some of them to be editable and some of them to be non-editable.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set the 'Protect' property of all the columns equal to the value of another, hidden column, either in the properties dialog or like this:

```
dw_1.Modify("column_name.Protect='hidden_column'")
```

Then on the rows you wish to be non-editable, set your hidden column value to 1.